# HTMLSession : cssselect.xpath.ExpressionError: Pseudo-elements are not supported

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm working on a web scraper project with `HTMLSession`, I plan to scrape Ask search engine results using a set of user-defined keywords. I have already started with writing the code for my scraper, here it is:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

class Scraper():
    def scrapedata(self,tag):
        url = f'https://www.ask.com/web?q={tag}'
        s = HTMLSession()
        r = s.get(url)
        print(r.status_code)

        qlist = []

        ask = r.html.find('div.PartialSearchResults-item')

        for a in ask:
            print(a.find('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link::text', first = True ).text.strip())


ask = Scraper()
ask.scrapedata('ferrari')
```

However when I run this code, instead of getting the list of all the web page titles related to the keywords searched in my terminal as it should have, I get the following errors:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\Beauty\scraper.py"
200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\Beauty\scraper.py", line 19, in <module>
    ask.scrapedata('ferrari')
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\Beauty\scraper.py", line 15, in scrapedata
    print(a.find('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link::text', first = True ).text.strip())
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 212, in find
    for found in self.pq(selector)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyquery\pyquery.py", line 261, in __call__
    result = self._copy(*args, parent=self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyquery\pyquery.py", line 247, in _copy
    return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyquery\pyquery.py", line 232, in __init__
    xpath = self._css_to_xpath(selector)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyquery\pyquery.py", line 243, in _css_to_xpath
    return self._translator.css_to_xpath(selector, prefix)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\cssselect\xpath.py", line 190, in css_to_xpath
    return ' | '.join(self.selector_to_xpath(selector, prefix,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\cssselect\xpath.py", line 190, in <genexpr>
    return ' | '.join(self.selector_to_xpath(selector, prefix,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\cssselect\xpath.py", line 222, in selector_to_xpath
    xpath = self.xpath_pseudo_element(xpath, selector.pseudo_element)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\cssselect\xpath.py", line 232, in xpath_pseudo_element
    raise ExpressionError('Pseudo-elements are not supported.')
cssselect.xpath.ExpressionError: Pseudo-elements are not supported.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 17.566 seconds
```

I don't even know what this means, I searched the Internet but instead came across problems related to IE7 and I don't see what has to do with my problem, especially since I'm using Microsoft Edge as my default web browser. Also, I hope to count on the help of more experienced members of the community to help me solve the problem. Thank you from Cameroon.

Comment: The `::text` part of your selector is a pseudo-element, and as the error message says, it is not supported. Instead, use `.find` to get the matching elements, then get the `.text` of each,. The other problem you'll run into is that you've written your code as though your `.find` will return a single element, but it doesn't. You'll need to iterate over the elements returned and get the `.text` of each.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `::text` [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KiMx.png) or `print(a.find("a.PartialsearchResults-item-title-link.result-link", first = True).text.strip())` and you will get the titles of your [Webpages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRHHl.png).

Comment: Please post the code as text here instead of links